# Unique customer identifier in Amazon Marketplace Web Services

Tags: amazon-mws

I am importing customers from Amazon to do an integration with our ordering system and want to avoid having duplicate customers as we do a high volume of sales on Amazon.

Is there any report, or API that will allow me to get a unique customer identifier that will never change for that customer no matter how many orders are placed?

I have thought of the anonymous email that Amazon makes available, however I am unsure if this changes, or if it is a static value as it is not referenced within the API documentation.

Has anyone else found a solution for this, or have any suggestion?

Comment: the key is buyer-email and is available from order reports or from amazon fulfilled shipments data report. 

The amazon fulfilled shipments data report will not contain buyer email information in certain circumstances, however the order reports will always contain the buyer email. 

Amazon's FAQ documentation states: 

Are there separate e-mail addresses per thread? 
No. The anonymised e-mail alias remains the same for all contacts that you have with each individual buyer. Use the buyer's anonymised e-mail address as a unique identifier to follow conversations across multiple orders.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted. This way, others will know that there is a solution.

Comment: As soon as min time passes and I have access to a computer I will :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the key is buyer-email and is available from order reports or from amazon fulfilled shipments data report.

The amazon fulfilled shipments data report will not contain buyer email information in certain circumstances, however the order reports will always contain the buyer email.

Amazon's FAQ documentation states:

Are there separate e-mail addresses per thread? No. The anonymised e-mail alias remains the same for all contacts that you have with each individual buyer. Use the buyer's anonymised e-mail address as a unique identifier to follow conversations across multiple orders.